# How to build WebGL for Augmented Reality in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ar-foundation

I tried 3timess it build successfully but after launching the browser there is no camera opened.?

Is any supported like vuforia, arfoundation? what is the methodology?

Answer (score 2):

For Unity WebAR, you will need to use a third party plugin which directly supports the WebGL platform, such as:

Subscribe to a WebAR platform:

- https://zap.works/universal-ar/unity

Purchase a paid asset store plugin:

- https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/camera/imagine-webar-image-tracker-240128

Or use open-source WebAR plugins like:

- https://github.com/ToughNutToCrack/ARWT
- https://github.com/taylordigital13/ARjs_Unity

Answer (score 0):

To create a WebGL projecy in Unity, you also need to add code to the already compiled project in the html page, which requests permission to use the camera on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Here I try to systemize Unity Assets that allow to run AR in WebGL:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/ar-for-webgl-with-unity.1412541/

Update (list of items) [ad]:

1. [Universal AR (UAR) SDK by Zappar Limited](https://makaka.org/o/uar)
2. [Augmented Reality WebGL — Image Tracking WebAR](https://makaka.org/o/webar)
3. [Imagine WebAR - World Tracker - WebGL - Plane Detection](https://makaka.org/o/webgl-plane)

Comment: Please do not answer with a link. Include the details  of the answer here as links become stale.